# integral problem with absolute value

Tags: calculus

I found out the answer is like $12.5$ by drawing triangles, but how do I do this using integrals?

$$\int_{-2}^5 | x - 1|\ dx$$

Is this setup right?

$$\int_{-2}^5 | x - 1|\ dx=\int_{-2}^1 1-x\ dx + \int_{1}^5 x - 1\ dx$$

Comment: It is right indeed, have you had any other problems with further calculations? Also is 12.5 an approximate answer?

Comment: That's correct...you should finish evaluating the integral +1